# Neo4j Cypher query and index of element in the collection

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to find index number of `Decision` by `{decisionGroupId}`, `{decisionId}` and `{criteriaIds}`

This is my current Cypher query:

```
MATCH (dg:DecisionGroup)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision) 
WHERE dg.id = {decisionGroupId} 
OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)-[vg:HAS_VOTE_ON]->(c:Criterion) 
WHERE c.id IN {criteriaIds} 
WITH childD, vg.avgVotesWeight as weight, vg.totalVotes as totalVotes 
ORDER BY weight DESC, totalVotes DESC 
WITH COLLECT(childD) AS ps 
RETURN REDUCE(ix = -1, i IN RANGE(0, SIZE(ps)-1) 
 | CASE ps[i].id WHEN {decisionId} THEN i ELSE ix END) AS ix
```

I have only 3 Decision in the database but this query returns the following indices:

```
2
3
4
```

while I expecting something like(starting from 0 and -1 if not found)

```
0
1
2
```

What is wrong with my query and how to fix it?

**UPDATED**

This query is working fine with `COLLECT(DISTINCT childD) AS ps`:

```
MATCH (dg:DecisionGroup)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision) 
WHERE dg.id = {decisionGroupId} 
OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)-[vg:HAS_VOTE_ON]->(c:Criterion) 
WHERE c.id IN {criteriaIds} 
WITH childD, vg.avgVotesWeight as weight, vg.totalVotes as totalVotes 
ORDER BY weight DESC, totalVotes DESC 
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT childD) AS ps 
RETURN REDUCE(ix = -1, i IN RANGE(0, SIZE(ps)-1) 
 | CASE ps[i].id WHEN {decisionId} THEN i ELSE ix END) AS ix
```

Please help me to refactor this query and get rid of heavy `REDUCE`.

Comment: [Reduce](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-reduce) is very powerful and is actually only required in rare cases, when you need to use the state of the accumulator variable. Here, I would first try a [list comprehension](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/lists/#cypher-list-comprehension): what result do you get with `RETURN [i IN RANGE(0, SIZE(ps)-1) | CASE ps[i].id WHEN {decisionId} THEN i ELSE -1 END] AS ix`

Comment: Thanks, with the provided pattern comprehension it returns something like this `[-1, 1, 2, -1, -1]` and not the exact index

Comment: That's odd. If `RETURN childD` returns 3 rows, changing it to `WITH collect(childD) AS ps RETURN [i IN RANGE(0, SIZE(ps)-1) | CASE ps[i].id WHEN {decisionId} THEN i ELSE -1 END] AS ix` should return a list of 3 items.

Comment: Okay, now I see why you used reduce. I'll add an answer in a minute.

Comment: One moment please, I'll update my question for more details. I found the reason of 5 elements instead of 3

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it is working like a charm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try to get the `reduce` part right with a simpler query:

```
WITH ['a', 'b', 'c'] AS ps
RETURN
  reduce(ix = -1, i IN RANGE(0, SIZE(ps)-1) |
    CASE ps[i] WHEN 'b' THEN i ELSE ix END) AS ix
  )
```

As I stated in the comments, it is usually better to avoid `reduce` if possible. So, to express the same using a [list comprehension](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/lists/#cypher-list-comprehension), use `WHERE` for filtering.

```
WITH ['a', 'b', 'c'] AS ps
RETURN [i IN RANGE(0, SIZE(ps)-1) WHERE ps[i] = 'b'][0]
```

The list comprehension results in a list with a single element, and we will use the `[0]` indexer to select that element.

After adapting this to your query, we'll get something like this:

```
MATCH (dg:DecisionGroup)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision) 
WHERE dg.id = {decisionGroupId} 
OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)-[vg:HAS_VOTE_ON]->(c:Criterion) 
WHERE c.id IN {criteriaIds} 
WITH childD, vg.avgVotesWeight as weight, vg.totalVotes as totalVotes 
ORDER BY weight DESC, totalVotes DESC 
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT childD) AS ps 
RETURN [i IN RANGE(0, SIZE(ps)-1) WHERE ps[i].id = {decisionId}][0]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have APOC installed, you can also use the function:

`return apoc.coll.indexOf([1,2,3],2)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. From the performance point of view - what is the preferable way - pure Cypher or APOC functions?

Comment: most often APOC i think